# Whose fault is it? Google's or Samsung's?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung

Like a lot of other owners of Samsung S5 smartphones, I had a lot of trouble and difficulty with my phone after installing the lolipop update. lollipop isn't working well with my phone, so my question is: Who's fault is it for that huge mistake? Is it Google or is it Samsung, because I didn't see such problems for manufacturers other than Samsung.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung. Google just provides a stock version of Android. It's Samsung's duty to make the OS Compatible with the phone. So, if the OS doesn't work, it is ultimately Samsung on whom the blame falls...

Comment: Thought so, but I needed to check.

Comment: Consider making this the cosen answer by clicking the 'v' on the right side...